# pythone ugettext

Tags: python

hi: 
   i have some code like this:

```
  from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _ 

  def desc():
   return _("%(user)s add this site") % {
        'user': self.friendly_username(viewer, self.user)} )
```

if `self.friendly_username(viewer, self.user)` return a English name , this code will have no problem , but if when the  `self.friendly_username(viewer, self.user)` return a chinese name like 爱情 , the desc will return None.

how can i slove this problem.

Comment: First, fix your code snippet so that we can clearly see what it actually looks like.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about the problem, as your code is not syntactically valid. In any case, I believe you want to do instead:

```
def desc():
   return _("%(user)s add this site") % {
        'user': self.friendly_username(viewer, self.user)}
```

So that your string does not depend on the user's name.